# Batch file battle system skills bug

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I've been recently working hard on a batch file text based rpg, faced several problems and solved them decently, so I got stuck with this problem:

I have got a combat skill that does a constant damage, and I want it to only be activated when enemy is equal or below 25% health, but I can't.

I tried to write it but it's not working. Like, totally ignoring the command, so I want to know what's wrong and how to fix it

**Code:**

```
:Wolf
cls
echo.
echo   Wolf     Hp: %WolfHp%\30
echo.
echo.
echo   %name%     Hp: %hp%\100
echo.
echo 1)Attack Wolf
echo 2)Swift Cut
echo.
set /p input=)
if %input%==1 goto HitWolf
if %input%==2 goto CutWolf
goto Wolf
```

:: I skipped to the skill directly VVV

```
:CutWolf
set num=%random:~-2%
if %num% gtr %dmg% goto CutWolf
if %num% lss 01 goto CutWolf
if %num%== 00 goto WolfMiss
if %num%== 01 goto WolfMiss
if %num%== 02 set num=%cut%
if %num%== 03 set num=%cut%
if %num%== 04 set num=%cut%
if %num%== 05 set num=%cut%
if %num%== 06 set num=%cut%
if %num%== 07 set num=%cut%
if %num%== 08 set num=%cut%
if %num%== 09 set num=%cut%
if %WolfHp% gtr %WolfHp%*25/100 goto Wolf
cls
echo.
echo    Swift Cut Success
echo.
echo   You swiftly cut the wolf, damage dealt: %cut%
pause >nul
if %WolfHp% gtr %WolfHp%*25/100 goto Wolf
set /a WolfHp= %WolfHp%-%num%
goto WolfAttack
```

Comment: besides, what SachaDee said, I don't catch the logic: X is always greater X/4 for positive integers (equal for "0", always smaller for negative numbers, which doesn't make sense for "HealthPoints")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in BAT :

```
if %WolfHp% gtr %WolfHp%*25/100 goto Wolf
```

But you can do this :

```
set /a tmp=%WolfHp%*25/100
if %WolfHp% gtr %tmp% goto Wolf
```

All calculation (arithmetic) have to be done/set with `set /a`. The `IF` test have to be done between 2 variables